# What happens to discussion history when you close a GitLab merge request

Tags: gitlab

If I close a GitLab merge request without merging it will I still be able to access the discussion history of the closed merge request?

I would like to close a merge request and split it into two requests, but I want to still be able to refer back to the discussion history of the original merge request for reference. If I will lose access to the original discussion history then I'll opt to keep that merge request open.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The merge request will still be there, with its history and discussion.

You would need to delete it ([as in "button delete"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49779365/6309)) in order for the discussion to not be accessible anymore.